# Magento 1.9.0.1 - Email Issue

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have an interesting issue that I'm hoping someone else has run into before. This is with Magento 1.9.0.1 CE.

Order/Sales emails are sending out fine but the emails are getting "www." appended to the domain portion of the emails of the site.  For example, if the sales contact email is johnsmith@domain.com, the system is changing the from email to johnsmith@www.domain.com.

I have no clue why its doing this. I did recently change the site from www.domain.com to domain.com, I'm not sure if this had anything to do it with?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question, but it looks like it was an issue with my /etc/hosts file. I had

> 127.0.0.1 localhost www.domain.com domain.com

changed to:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost domain.com www.domain.com

As simple as that!